# How to pass JSON from materialTopTabNavigator to other screen component react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a JSON and it is passed from one component to another Component and there are different component screen tabs how can I pass that JSON from the main MyTabs component to other component screens. Here id variable consists of JSON data how can I Pass it Home and settings component.

```
const tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Mytabs = (props) =>{
const id = props.route.params;
return(

 <tab.Navigator   initialRouteName="home" >
  <tab.Screen  name="home" component={HomeScreen}   />
  <tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen}  />
 </tab.Navigator>
  
 );
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React navigation screens have an `initialParams` prop you can use to pass `id`.

From the documentation:

> You can also pass some initial params to a screen. If you didn't specify any params when navigating to this screen, the initial params will be used. They are also shallow merged with any params that you pass. Initial params can be specified with an initialParams prop.

```
...
<tab.Screen
  name="home"
  component={HomeScreen}
  initialParams={{ id: id }}
/>
<tab.Screen
  name="Settings"
  component={SettingsScreen}
  initialParams={{ id: id }}
/>
...
```

To retrieve the initial params in a component do the following:

```
function HomeScreen({route}) {
   const {id} = route.params
   ... // Do something with the id
}
```

Read https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/ to see all the ways you can pass params to routes.

Comment: when using initialParams I got Error: A navigator can only contain 'Screen' Component as its direct children (found '[object,Object]).

Comment: Could edit your question and add what the code looks like now? That sounds like a syntax error.

Comment: Yeah there was a syntax error, but now when I pass using initialParams I am getting a number 964 which is no where present in my json  when I console log on the component where I receive and when I console log  "id.class" i get undefined, class is the json object.

Comment: That is not a problem with `initialParams`, but means that you are not passing the data correctly as props to `Mytabs`.

Comment: Thanx a lot it worked I was directly using the id passed from the initialParams, Can you suggest any other way by which we can pass this data without using initialParams.